# Marshall structure to pointer for List of Object in C#

Tags: c#, marshalling

I have list of object, have to do marshalling from structure to pointer and send to Unmanaged code,

```
IntPtr buffer = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(StructClassA)) * ListClassA.Length);
for (int Index = 0; Index < ListClassA.Length; Index++)
{
       var intrt = (IntPtr)(buffer.ToInt64() + (Index * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(StructClassA))));
       Marshal.StructureToPtr(ListClassA[Index], intrt, false);
}

ClassA
{
    public float floatA;
    public float floatB;
    public float floatC;

    public ushort Id;
    public short ints;
    public byte type;
}
```

is this right way to do or any better option to do marshaling?
Problem is, if the list contains 300 to 500 objects then we have to loop that many time.

Comment: much depends on what `StructClassA`... if it is blittable or not. You'll have to show it to us. And `ListClassA` is a `List<>`? And remember that you have to `Marshal.DestroyStructure` each structure you have `Marshal.StructureToPtr`.

Comment: @xanatos, I added struct of Class A into question section. ListClassA is List<ClassA>. Yes im doing the Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer) after sending to unmanaged code.

Comment: If `ClassA` is `class` then you can't do anything different. If it is `struct` then it is possible to do something different.

Comment: And depending on the content of the marshaled structure (if there are `string` for example), you have to do `Marshal.DestroyStructure` **for each** single structure. One `Marshal.StructureToPtr` == one `Marshal.DestroyStructure`. Doing `Marshal.FreeHGlobal(buffer)` isn't enough. In this case it isn't necessary because the contained data are only numbers.

Comment: If you want this fast and easy then you have to use an array instead of a List and declare the element type as struct instead of class.  Now the pinvoke marshaller can avoid copying and simply pass a pointer to the first array element.  Big, big difference.  Maybe you dislike giving up on List, but adapting code to work better with unmanaged interop is pretty normal.

Comment: It is possible with reflection to extract the internal `T[]` buffer of a `List<T>` and pass it around... Ugly but doable.

Comment: @HansPassant, changing from list is to array is ok, why should we use struct instead of class? is there any major difference?

Comment: @user1645200 Because as is you are passing a `ClassA*` to C (use it like `classA[5].floatA`). If you use `StructA[]` you can still pass without copy a `StructA*` to C. But if you use `ClassA[]` then you would be passing a `ClassA**` to C (use it like `classA[5]->floatA`), and you would need to pin each single `ClassA` inside the array.